# Firebase Firestore returning true on failed document delete

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app which uses Firebase's Firestore for persistence. I am using Material's Snackbar for notifications. I have in my service..

```
deleteProvider(data) {
    return this.db.collection(data.table).doc('xzc').delete();
  }
```

Where the data param is simply an object containing the table which I want to perform the action on and the id of the document I wish to delete.

```
data: { table: 'providers', id: 'some firebase identifier'}
```

And in my component

```
onDeleteEntry(event) {
    if (event.table === 'providers') {
      this.providerService.deleteProvider(event)
        .then(() => {
          this.snackBar.open('Provider deleted');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.snackBar.open('Error deleting provider', error);
        });
    }
  }
```

This deletes the document perfectly, but on testing the failed case, it returns true.

For example, if I hard-code 'xyz' into the .doc('xyz') method. The response calls my next() method, rather than my my catch().

```
deleteProvider(data) {
    return this.db.collection(data.table).doc('xyz').delete();
  } // returns true on a non-existent document
```

The Firebase docs emphasise the fact that nested collections will remain after deletion but other than that, the basic functionality of deleting a document is simple and doesn't give very much information other than

```
db.collection("cities").doc("DC").delete().then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
});
```

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: It might be the case that delete() always resolves successfully, regardless if the document previously existed.  In that case, it would just be telling you that you can be sure that the document currently doesn't exist, not that it previously existed and now does not.  If you want to know that it previously existed, try a transaction that fetches the document first, checks for existence, then deletes it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Doug. That makes sense. It would be nice to test the failed-case though and I would have thought that deleting a non-existent document would have done it. I'll #askfirebase for clarification.

Comment: Don't try to force your definition of "failure" on the API.  A true failure would be the case where a document does exist, and you ask for it to be deleted, but that didn't happen.  Again, try a transaction to ensure that you're only deleting a document that previously exists, if that knowledge is important to you.

Comment: Noted. Cheers, Doug

Comment: I'm coming at it from the opposite direction. I want to make sure something doesn't exist before I create a new document (which will also trigger a cloud function via `onCreate`), so I call `delete()` whether or not it exists beforehand. This conversation lets me know that will work.

Comment: I tested this and used a non existing docId and a non existing collection name. `delete()` always works without any error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, `delete` does **not** fail if a document doesn't exist. In a way, this is inconsistent with `create`, which does fail if it exists beforehand.

However, it looks like this feature is/was planned. In Java SDK, `delete` can take a `Precondition` object:

```java
  /**
   * Deletes the document referred to by this DocumentReference.
   *
   * @param options Preconditions to enforce for this delete.
   * @return An ApiFuture that will be resolved when the delete completes.
   */
  @Nonnull
  public ApiFuture<WriteResult> delete(@Nonnull Precondition options) {
    WriteBatch writeBatch = firestore.batch();
    return extractFirst(writeBatch.delete(this, options).commit());
  }
```

In `Precondition`, there is a helper method:

```java
  /**
   * Creates a Precondition that enforces that a document exists.
   *
   * @param exists Whether the document should exist.
   * @return A new Precondition
   */
  // TODO: Make public once backend supports verify.
  @Nonnull
  static Precondition exists(Boolean exists) {
    return new Precondition(exists, null);
  }
```

Note that is not public. The comment says it lacks backend support. Only Firestore team knows the current status of it.

Comment: Almost a year to the day :p
Thanks, Nikola and well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

["exists" precondition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Precondition)  works for me

```
    const batch = db.batch();
    const toDeleteRef = db.collection("somecollection").doc("someid");
    const counterRef = db.collection("somecollection").doc("count");
    batch.delete(toDeleteRef, {exists:true});
    batch.set(counterRef, {value:firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)}, {merge:true});
    await batch.commit();
```